# Cancelling an inoremap

Tags: vim

Consider the following `.vimrc` configuration:

```
inoremap ' ''<left>
function! someFunc()
     inoremap ' '
```

Now, after someFunc() is run, pressing <kbd>'</kbd> still waits the timeout time before moving the cursor. Can the original `inoremap` be cancelled rather than overwritten to remove the wait?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you want to use `iunmap '`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redefining won't work, unmap instead:

```
iunmap '
```